# JPA exception : More than one row with the given identifier was found

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am developing application with `Spring Boot`, `Vaadin` and `JPA`.

I created 3 entity classes:

**Author:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "patronymic")
    private String patronymic;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Book> books;
```

**Genre:**

```
@Entity(name = "genre")
@Table(name = "genre")
public class Genre {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "genre", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Book book;
```

The book is related to the author (many books - one author) and genre (one genre - one book)

**Book:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")
    private Genre genre;
    
    
    @Column(name = "publisher")
    private String publisher;

    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
```

.. and when I run my spring boot application I get the error.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 3, for class: com.app.entity.Book

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: At first sight it looks like a db issue. Have you browsed your db ? "select * from book". There might be 3 rows with the same id.

Comment: in table "book" the primary key "id" is unique for each row

Comment: Are fetching any data any from the repository method?

Comment: What about relation Genre<->Book ? Did not you associate more than one with the same of them ?